# popspringanimation very choppy in UINavigationController Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-pop

In UINavigationController Delegate I add pop animation in the transition, what I did is as following:

```
- (NSTimeInterval) transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    return self.duration;
}

- (void) animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    // I get some cell from initialization
    UIImageView *avatarImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    avatarImage.image = _cell.avatarImageView.image;
    avatarImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
    avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = avatarImage.frame.size.width/2.0;
    CGFloat originSize = avatarImage.frame.size.width;
    [fromViewController.view addSubview:avatarImage];
    CGFloat avatarSize = CURRENT_SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.15;
    CGFloat avatarPositionY = CURRENT_SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.4;
    POPSpringAnimation *animation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerPosition];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(CURRENT_SCREEN_WIDTH/2.0, avatarPositionY + avatarSize/2.0 - 64)];
    animation.springBounciness = 2.0;
    [avatarImage.layer pop_addAnimation:animation forKey:@"move"];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        toViewController.view.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
        [imageView removeFromSuperview];
        [avatarImage removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

But the problem is, it's not smooth at all, what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple problems;

- Your image is very big (in memory)
- The corner radius isn't helping either
- You're doing something else on the main thread during during this animation

Try the following and see if the animation is smooth after each change:

Remove/comment:

```
avatarImage.image = _cell.avatarImageView.image;
```

Remove/comment:

```
avatarImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = avatarImage.frame.size.width/2.0;
```